# Unzip file on SFTP Server

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have connected to my remote server via FTP and i put some zip file using following code.

```
channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR + "/" + remoteDestinationDir);
File file = new File(localSourceToFile);
LOG.info("Transferring file: " + localSourceToFile + " to "+ SFTPWORKINGDIR + "/" + remoteDestinationDir);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
channelSftp.put(fis, file.getName());
fis.close();
LOG.info("Transfer successful");
```

Now, I want to unzip file on server

Comment: How is this related to java?

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to do. Are you connected with java (hence the tag?) or with a ftp client program? You can download the files and unzip them locally. Depending on the ftp client and server, you might be able to execute a command which will display the content of the file remotely or even unzip it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ChannelSftp doesn't support executing commands on the server side. It mainly deals with the transfer of files. You can use ChannelExec
https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html to execute unzip /path/to/uploaded/file.zip.

Alternatively, you could have a job running on the server side which watches the directory you upload files to and upzip any uploaded zip-files automatically.